# WEP: response computation for shared key authentication

Tags: authentication, crc32, wep

after a very long research on the web, I'm still not able to find any code/algorithm that shows how the shared-key authentication works in WEP, and in particular how the response is computed.

The general concept is clear:

- The mobile station (MB) sends a connect request to the access
  point (AP).
- The AP replies with a challenge
- The MB encrypts this challenge (it has to prove to have the shared key) and sends it back to the AP
- The AP verifies the cypher text and allows the access.

Now:

The challenge is 128 bytes.

How is the response computed? When opening in wireshark the traffic, the response is usually 136 bytes, meaning that the encryption includes also something else.

This should be something like:

RC4 ( IV + challenge + CRC32(challenge))

Where can I verify if this expression is the correct one?

Furthermore:

- the IV is 6 Hex digit (so 3 bytes) meaning that maybe there is an extension of one byte. How is this extension computed?
- the challenge is 128 bytes
- is the CRC-32 computed on the challenge text only? Does it include also the IV?

Could you please refer to any official document where I can find the complete specification of the fields involved in the computation?
Thanks